# How to detect a redirect with javascript in MediaWiki

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, fetch-api

I'd like to detect if a URL in a MediaWiki points to a redirect. When I run the following script on en.wikipedia.org:

```js
let test = await fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Wayne');
console.log(test.url);        // → https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Wayne
console.log(test.redirected); // → false
```

yet when I enter `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Wayne` into the address bar I get redirected to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman#Bruce_Wayne` instead.

How can I detect with JavaScript if a Url gets redirected to a different document? And can I find out without fetching the whole document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a sepatate request to wiki API, e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Wikipedia:!--&redirects&format=json&formatversion=2.
Result will be:

```json
{
    "batchcomplete": true,
    "query": {
        "redirects": [
            {
                "from": "Wikipedia:!--",
                "to": "Wikipedia:Manual of Style",
                "tofragment": "Invisible comments"
            }
        ],
        "pages": [
            {
                "pageid": 33697,
                "ns": 4,
                "title": "Wikipedia:Manual of Style"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note the `query.redirects` part.
Examples are taken from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Resolving_redirects.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of [Response.redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected) and [Response.url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url) on detecting redirects.

You can make a HEAD request to avoiding fetching whole documents. It will trigger CORS behavior on cross-domain requests though. You could also use Wikipedia's API to see if a page is a redirect, instead of fetching the page, but chances are it will be slower for you and more load for the server - Wikipedia is highly optimized for normal pageviews.

Comment: i should have mentioned that I don't have to deal with cross domain restrictions

Comment: according to `Response.redirected` there is no redirect

Comment: Well, there isn't one in your example. `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Wayne` returns the same HTML as `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman`, without redirecting you anywhere. When the page is loaded, a piece of Javascript changes the displayed URL and scrolls to the section. If you want to detect article redirects (which are not HTTP redirects), you'll have to use the API as Alexander says.

Comment: I am really disappointed about how mediawiki handles redirects at this point

Comment: It results in better page performance and less server load. Scripting is not much or a priority compared to that. Depending on what you are after, you could try `https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/html/Bruce_Wayne`, that will be a proper redirect. (The content is not quite the same though.)